# Error while building the node-gyp

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp

I had a *.cc file which contains the source file and while building the same using a node-gyp, it is throwing a strange error -

*"#error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /M
D[d]"*

In the source file implementation, I am loading a MFC DLL.
Do I need to add any settings in the node-gyp file ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the issue by adding '#define _AFXDLL' in .cc file.
Thank you